# I have a string `-2½`, need to be converted in float -2.5

Tags: python, string, floating-point

i have tried to replace this `½` part with `.5`, but still it says on the first line, got '\xc2' non-ASCII character. no encoding declared.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- ` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: Thanks @FilipMłynarski

Comment: you can add your comment to answer, i'll accept.

Comment: I can't because your question was marked as duplicate, but thanks :)